# Is it possible to pass the spring.cloud.config.uri along with the docker run command?

Tags: java, spring, docker

I'm a beginner to docker and hence the doubt. I have a simple spring boot application fetching properties from a config server. I want to dockerize my application and have a static image that can be used across environments. Assuming the config server url will change in higher environments , is it possible to pass the config server url (spring.cloud.config.uri) along with the docker run command? My docker file has an ENTRYPOINT mentioning java -jar  for starting the application.

Comment: Just specify an docker Environment variable `SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI` with the desired value whilst starting your docker container.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! Same as how you pass SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE i assume?

Comment: It is exactly the same, for any property for that matter.

Comment: @M.Deinum If you can add it as an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [Spring Boot reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) Spring Boot will read properties from different sources. One of those sources is the environment.

It is also documented that relaxed binding can be used to bind properties. The latter means that `spring.profiles.active` and `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` will both work to specify the active profile. This applies to ALL properties that Spring Boot tries to resolve, so it also applies to `spring.cloud.config.uri`.

Using Docker you can specify [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) those will be available in the container as environment variables.

Those 2 things combined make it possible to supply values to Spring Boot through Docker Environment variables.

```
docker run --env SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG-URI=<your-environment-url-here> -d -p 8080:8080 <container-id>
```

Comment: Should that say SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ URI not SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG-URI?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use `docker service create` command to launch my container. Along with this I pass my argument ex: `CONFIG_URI` as an argument.

`docker service create --name <image_name> -e CONFIG_URI="<your URI>" ......`

In my Spring Boot application I would accept CONFIG_URI as a environment variable into my application properties.

spring.cloud.config.uri=${CONFIG_URI}

In my entrypoint file I simply mention something like the following

`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=qa`